# How to scan ':' delimitted integer inputs in java?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, numberformatexception

I have an input of integers :

```
2
90:01:23 42:01
12:89:21 21:67
```

I tried using

```
line = scan.nextLine() ;  
String[]  tokens =  line.split(":| ");
 int first =  Integer.parseInt( tokens[0]);
```

but it gives me

```
NumberFormatException
```

I want to parse these int to 5 variables.

The input parsed must be in order :

```
90, 1, 23, 42, 1
```

Please help me parse this input.

Comment: why do u have spaces in number?

Comment: its an input of 2 ratios. the space in between is to differentiate two ratios. Also in first line, 10 is an input for another parameter not related to ratios.

Comment: I do not get a `NumberFormatException`.  Please show us (1) the **exact** value of the input lines.  Make sure we can see any spaces that occur at the beginning or end of the lines, and that we can see any place where there is more than one consecutive space; and (2) the exact value of `tokens[0]`, in the same manner.

Comment: what is your expected output for `input 2`?

Comment: not able to indent the input, as i am currently on my tab and it doesnt allow me to add code snippets.

Comment: What do you mean by "you are on your tab"?  If you edit the question, highlight a part of it that you want to show up as a code snippet, and click on the `{}` icon, it should format it for you.  Is there some reason you can't do this?

Comment: thanks ajb, i could format it now

Comment: Thank you.  You say you want to parse all 5 integers.  Your code only parses one.  So don't you need a loop?  And shouldn't you be looking at all the tokens, not just `tokens[0]`?  As it is, you're looking at only one token, and your code still doesn't throw an exception for me.  Did you leave out some code?  I think you need to post a more complete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
String s = " 90:01:23 42:01";
s = s.trim();
String[] sArr = s.split(":|\\s+");
for(String str : sArr) {
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str));
}
```